# Update RTC drift file (adjtime) from NTP updates

Tags: ntp, ntpd

I'm trying to improve the accuracy of the RTC clock on a buildroot embedded system that I'm working with. I need it to be accurate to 10 seconds over 2 weeks, while switched off and powered but offline.

So I've added drift files for both NTP and the hwclock and I'm looking at when these files should be updated while the system is online. Updating the hardware drift on shutdown doesn't seem viable (I imagine these systems aren't shutdown cleanly often), and our system has a delay on internet connectivity on startup which may cause issues on having the NTP clock synced to system time, nor would updating on shutdown or startup guarantee that the system clock has been updated by NTP recently. I could update with a cron job, but that doesn't guarantee a good update recently either.

I could calculate the drift once statically for an individual system and just use that for all of the systems. However I imagine temperature variation may change the drift value throughout the year.

NTPd was always configured to update the RTC on this system, it's not accurate enough without a drift file. And by experimentation it doesn't appear to update the calculated hardware drift. It would be great if the '11 minute mode' of NTPd could update the `adjtime` file every 4 hours or more (every 2 weeks would be ideal).

Can anyone suggest what the optimal configuration would be?